# Class object as template funciton argument

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

I have an issue with the templates and my knowledge about them is definitely limited. 
So I have a class which should store some information:

```
class Q
{
    int integer;
    int fractional;
  public:
    constexpr Q(int i,int f) : integer(i),fractional(f) {}
    int get_i() const {return this->integer;}
    int get_f() const {return this->fractional;}
    constexpr int get_w() {return this->integer + this->fractional;}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Q& q){ os << "Q" << q.integer << "." << q.fractional << " (w:" << q.integer + q.fractional << ")"; return os; }
};
```

Then I have my templated function. This is just an example but it show the point:

```
template <Q input_q, Q output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
{ 
  std::array<Q,input_q.get_w()> input_queue_q;
}
```

And at the end the main (I'm using the SystemC library) where I generate the constant object `Q` that I want to use in the function

```
int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  constexpr Q Q1_i = Q(1,10);
  constexpr Q Q1_o = Q(0,11);

  // Number of bits used to address the LUT for the initial value
  const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit = 5;

  // Number of iteration for the Newton-Raphson
  const int max_iterations = 2;

  calculate_stuff <Q1_i,Q1_o,X_0_evaluated_bit> (max_iterations);
  return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile I get the following error message:

```
check_ac_one_over.cpp:31:13: error: ‘class Q’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
 template <Q input_q, Q output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
             ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:31:24: error: ‘class Q’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
 template <Q input_q, Q output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
                        ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp: In function ‘void calculate_stuff(int)’:
check_ac_one_over.cpp:33:31: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   std::array<Q,input_q.get_w()> input_queue_q;
                               ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:33:46: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
   std::array<Q,input_q.get_w()> input_queue_q;
                                              ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp: In function ‘int sc_main(int, char**)’:
check_ac_one_over.cpp:102:64: error: no matching function for call to ‘calculate_stuff(const int&)’
   calculate_stuff <Q1_i,Q1_o,X_0_evaluated_bit> (max_iterations);
                                                                ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:102:64: note: candidate is:
check_ac_one_over.cpp:31:76: note: template<<typeprefixerror>input_q, <typeprefixerror>output_q, unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff(int)
 template <Q input_q, Q output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
                                                                            ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:31:76: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
check_ac_one_over.cpp:102:64: note: invalid template non-type parameter
   calculate_stuff <Q1_i,Q1_o,X_0_evaluated_bit> (max_iterations);
                                                                ^
check_ac_one_over.cpp:102:64: note: invalid template non-type parameter
make: *** [check_ac_one_over.o] Error 1
```

Now I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. Does anyone have some ideas how can I make it work ?

Cheers,

Stefano

Comment: Why did you turn your function into a template? You might have gotten stuck halfway down a bad path, and it would be a disservice to help you continue.

Comment: Well, I didn't tell all the story. Inside the templated function there are several others templated functions. Those functions have to be templated they represents hardware modules (I'm using the SystemC library). There are rules those have to be followed when you write hardware with the SystemC library even because the tool that translate from C++ in RTL are quite picky.

Comment: That does not explain why the outer function needs to be a template. Also, there is this classic programming concept called "GIGO", which in this case would say that if you ask an incomplete question, you'll get incomplete answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. It's not the perfect one but it's quite close. Instead to use the object I'm using the pointer to the object which has become a global variable:

```
class Q
{
    int integer;
    int fractional;
  public:
    constexpr Q(int i = 0,int f = 0) : integer(i),fractional(f) {}
    constexpr int get_i() const {return this->integer;}
    constexpr int get_f() const {return this->fractional;}
    constexpr int get_w() const {return this->integer + this->fractional;}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Q& q){ os << "Q" << q.integer << "." << q.fractional << " (w:" << q.integer + q.fractional << ")"; return os; }
};


template <const Q *input_q,const Q *output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit> void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
{ 
  std::array<Q,input_q->get_w()> input_queue_q;
}


constexpr Q Q1_i = Q(1,10);
constexpr Q Q1_o = Q(0,11);

int sc_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  // Number of bits used to address the LUT for the initial value
  const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit = 5;

  // Number of iteration for the Newton-Raphson
  const int max_iterations = 2;

  calculate_stuff <&Q1_i,&Q1_o,X_0_evaluated_bit> (max_iterations);
  return 0;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I would not say this comes close to a perfect solution, although you might be starting down a productive road. Try this as an exercise: move the definitions of `Q1_i` and `Q1_o` above your templated function. Next, move the definition of `x_0_evaluated_bit` to global scope, putting it right after the definition of `Q1_o`. Now remove the text `template <const Q *input_q,const Q *output_q,const unsigned int X_0_evaluated_bit>` and `<&Q1_i,&Q1_o,X_0_evaluated_bit>`. Change `input_q->get_w()` to `Q1_i.get_w()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have some ideas how can I make it work ?

Not a great idea, I suppose, but...

The error message is clear:

> ‘class Q’ is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

But, in your example, you don't use the full `Q` object: you use the value of `input_q.get_w()`.

So I suppose that you can pass as template parameter not the full `Q` object but only the value returned by `get_w()` that is a `int` so is a valid as template non-type parameter.

Something (using only the first template parameter; no idea about the use of the other)

```
template <int input_dim>
void calculate_stuff (const int max_iterations)
 { 
   std::array<Q, input_dim> input_queue_q;
 }
```

that you can call (taking in count that `Q1_i` and `get_w()` are `constexpr`)

```
calculate_stuff<Q1_i.get_w()> (1);
```

But observe that

1) `get_w()` should be also `const`, not only `constexpr`

```
  constexpr int get_w() const {return this->integer + this->fractional;}
```

because a `constexpr` method isn't automatically `const` (starting from C++14) but a `constexpr` object is also `const` (so can't use `get_w()` if it isn't defined `const`)

2) If you want an array of `Q` as follows

```
std::array<Q, input_dim> input_queue_q;
```

the `Q` type require a constructor without parameters; by example adding default values to your constructor

```
constexpr Q(int i = 0, int f = 0) : integer(i),fractional(f) {}
```

Comment: I thought that, It was my first approach. I wanted to do in this other way, in order to keep  clean and easy the setup. Just to clarify a bit. That method is not the only one that I use. I'm basically using inside the function 2 Q objects and from the I need to now the integer and fractional. So it is going to be a templated function with at least 4 arguments...which is not really elegant.

Comment: I guess the solution is to transform that argument in a pointer. In this case it should be a valid non-type and I should be able to do what I want. Right ?

Comment: @haster8558 - to keep it clean... it's necessary that the values are in non-static members? What about a collection of static constexpr members? This way you can pass a single typename.